# "express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option node_modules/admin-bro-expressjs/plugin.js:138:14"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, admin

am using admin-bro for my admin , it works fine until i try to use its authentication, when i try to login to the admin using the admin-bro login form dashboard ,it just keeps loading with no response,my terminal says

> express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option node_modules/admin-bro-expressjs/plugin.js:138:14
>
> express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option node_modules/admin-bro-expressjs/plugin.js :138:14 AdminBro: bundle ready we're connected!

here's my app.js file

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const engine = require('ejs-mate');
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('./models/user');
//const formidableMiddleware = require('express-formidable');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
// const seedPosts = require('./seeds');
// seedPosts();

// require routes
const index     = require('./routes/index');
const posts     = require('./routes/posts');
const reviews = require('./routes/reviews');
const adminRouter= require('./routes/admin.router');

const app = express();

//connect to database
//var url = process.env.DATABASEURL || "mongodb://localhost:27017/surf-shop"
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/surf-shop" , {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('we\'re connected!');
});

// use ejs-locals for all ejs templates:
app.engine('ejs', engine);
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// set public assets directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favi.jpg')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

// Configure Passport and Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'hang ten dude!',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(User.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// set local variables middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // req.user = {
  //   // '_id' : '5bb27cd1f986d278582aa58c',
  //   // '_id' : '5bc521c0b142b6d7f7523406',
  //   '_id' : '5bfed10ad176f845e38aec92',
  //   'username' : 'ian3'
  // }
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  // set default page title
  res.locals.title = 'Surf Shop';
  // set success flash message
  res.locals.success = req.session.success || '';
  delete req.session.success;
  // set error flash message
  res.locals.error = req.session.error || '';
  delete req.session.error;
  // continue on to next function in middleware chain
  next();
});

// Mount routes
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/posts', posts);
app.use('/posts/:id/reviews', reviews);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);

//app.use(formidableMiddleware());


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // // set locals, only providing error in development
  // res.locals.message = err.message;
  // res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // // render the error page
  // res.status(err.status || 500);
  // res.render('error');
  console.log(err);
  req.session.error = err.message;
  res.redirect('back');
});

module.exports = app;
```

here's my admin.route.js file

```
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');
const AdminBroExpress = require('admin-bro-expressjs');
const AdminBroMongoose = require('admin-bro-mongoose');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

AdminBro.registerAdapter(AdminBroMongoose);

const adminBro = new AdminBro({
  databases: [mongoose], 
  rootPath: '/admin',
});

const ADMIN = {
  email: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL || 'admin@example.com',
  password: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD || 'lovejs',
}

const router = AdminBroExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(adminBro, {
    cookieName: process.env.ADMIN_COOKIE_NAME || 'admin-bro',
    cookiePassword: process.env.ADMIN_COOKIE_PASS || 'some-super-sensitive-password',
    authenticate: async (email, password) => {
    if (ADMIN.password === password && ADMIN.email === email) {
      return ADMIN
    }
    return null

    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Put your `app.use('/admin', adminRouter);` before `app.use(express.json());`

That was how I solved the problem because admin bro has an issue with express body parser or the built in one.

Answer (score 0):

delete `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`